# What is the best way to validate a nested model with Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Coming from a [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) background,  I often find myself composing *Form Requests* to validate nested models.

In my case, I have a *Model* which has many (1..*) *NestedModel*.  *Model* MUST be created with *NestedModel*.  The payload I receive looks like so:

```
{
    "model": {
        "nested_model": {
            // ...
        },
        // ...
    }
}
```

The only time the *NestedModel* is required in the *Model*'s payload is on my *ModelController@create* endpoint.  *NestedModel*s have their own endpoints.

How would I go around implementing this with *changeset*s since I would like to validate my payload first and then save both models to my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate nested model in Ecto can use [cast_assoc/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3)